# Alamofire flat error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have some problem with GET method Alamofire. When I get data I have error:

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong? My code:

```
        let URLString = "http://MyURLWebService...";
        Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString)
        .responseJSON { (response) in 
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print(JSON["Phones"] as! String)
                //print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }

    }
```

Comment: My format REST API data:

[{Phones":"+1 (100) 111-22-33","Phones2":null}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is work:

```
            if let jsonResult = response.result.value {
                let Address = jsonResult[0]["Address"]
                let Phones = jsonResult[0]["Phones"]
                print("JSON:    Address: \(Address)")
                print("JSON: Phones: \(Phones)")
            }
```

I hope it help somebody

Answer (score 0):

I think the `JSON` object has no member with `"Phones"` as name. So it's better to use **?** instead **!**.
`print(JSON["Phones"] as? String)`

Edit:

Your Json string is corrupted. You must wrap `Phones` with double quotations.

like this:

`[{"Phones":"+1 (100) 111-22-33","Phones2":null}]`